# Does Reheating Bishul Akum Affect Utensils?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory

Bishul Akum is prohibited to be eaten. And based on these answers once the food is bishul akum it seems like it would remain so unless something drastic happened.

But even if the food is prohibited: if one were to eat at a vegan restaurant such that all the ingredients are kasher ( since battel b'shishim/rov and eino ben yomo would apply since there aren't any consistent ingredient issues) and he/she brings food home to heat up this bishul akum food in their house, does it render the pots/pans/ovens compromised and needing to be re-kashered?

Comment: Have you seen [http//www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bishul_Akum] it appears comprhensive and comments upon kashering including rferences.

Comment: @gamliela thank you for the link. Seems rather comprehensive!